# treq request blocking twisted loop

Tags: python, django, post, python-requests, twisted

I'm trying to send an API POST Request to my local api within the twisted loop using treq. For some reason, I start the service running and it only actually does anything after I press Ctrl-C to exit the process where it just prints a bunch of crazy error messages because everything it relies on is now `None`. Here is the code I use to set up, send, and deal with the response from the request:

```
def history_event(self, <params>):

    # ...

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Token {auth_token}'.format(auth_token=settings.MASTER_API_TOKEN)}
    url = "http://{LAN_IP}/api/call-history/{uuid}/".format(LAN_IP=settings.LAN_IP, uuid=tuuid)
    api_req = APIRequest(url=url, data=kwargs, method='POST', headers=headers)

    req = treq.request('POST', url, data=kwargs, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    req.addCallback(self.check_api_post, api_req)
    req.addErrback(self.queue_api_request, api_req)
```

This is part of a django app, so settings is just a reference to the settings file. `APIRequest` is basically just a `dict`, so don't worry about that. Also, the params sent to the function are irrelevant to the problem, and would take too long to explain. They've already been processed correctly before this snippet.

The callback `self.check_api_post` is:

```
def check_api_post(self, response, api_request):
    status_code = response.code
    reason = response.content()
    http_error_msg = ''

    if 400 <= status_code < 500:
        http_error_msg = '%s Client Error: %s' % (status_code, reason)

    elif 500 <= status_code < 600:
        http_error_msg = '%s Server Error: %s' % (status_code, reason)

    if http_error_msg:
        self.queue_api_request(response, api_request, http_error_msg)
```

And finally the errback `self.queue_api_request` is:

```
def queue_api_request(self, response, api_request, err_msg=None):
    if err_msg:
        self.log_error("Request failed with message: {}".format(err_msg))
    else:
        self.log_error("Actual Request failed")

    req = api_request
    producer = APIProducer(self.call_driver.rep_channel.realm.amqp)
    producer.push(req)
```

All that does is use our class based amqp queue (twisted safe I know because we use it all over the place inside the twisted loop and it implements [`txamqp`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txAMQP)).

Why is this blocking the twisted loop? Why is it giving me tons of grief?! Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I must be doing twisted entirely wrong or something. Please go easy on me because I'm still totally lost on how to write good twisted code... so as an added bonus if anyone knows of an amazing twisted tutorial... please comment. Thanks in advance for all your answers, and please ask for clarification or more information if you want it! :)

**Edit:** Here's what I get back in one of my log messages:

> Request failed with message: 401 Client Error:

First of all, the 401 should be an unauthorized error and doesn't really make any sense there. Second, why is `response.content()` a deferred...? Should I yield to that? Would that fix this?

**Edit 2:** Just as another update, I tried yielding to both the `treq.request()`, and `response.content()` each to no avail. yielding to `response.content()` did pop up the fact that no Auth credentials were provided (which makes no sense because they are, so anyone that can tell me how I'm providing the token auth header wrong, please do. But... That still doesn't help me with the main part of the question, I only got that answer after I pressed Ctrl-C and the reactor was forcibly stopped... :( Which doesn't make any sense!

Please, someone help me with this. Point me in the right direction.

**Edit 3:** While looking through the logs I also came upon this interesting traceback that keeps popping up, and doesn't make much sense...

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/callcenter/current/ppcc/server/daemon.py", line 25, in start_one
    self.ppcc.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ppcc/server/manager.py", line 205, in run
    reactor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1192, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 797, in runUntilCurrent
    f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 379, in callback
    assert not isinstance(result, Deferred)
exceptions.AssertionError:
```

Maybe that will help someone with my problem...? Thanks in advance again!

**Edit 4:** I've also tried [`txrequests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txrequests) and twisted's built in [`getPage()`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.getPage.html), each to no avail. I fixed the 401 error by changing my apache WSGI settings (turning `WSGIPassAuthorization On`), but it still won't make the request until I press CTRL-C, which... I can't really do in production.

Comment: Can you consider turning this code into an http://sscce.org ?  There's far too much going on here to provide a comprehensive answer.  I'd have to guess at what huge amounts of code in your application are doing.  Ideally you could simulate the django/mod_wsgi shenanigans by just having a script that starts up and runs a background Twisted loop using Crochet (is that how you're doing it here?)

Comment: For what it's worth, the `AssertionError` you're seeing there is what happens when you call `Deferred.callback()` with a `Deferred` instance.  The line it's being called from suggests it's coming from the thread call queue, which means somebody did `callFromThread(d.callback, Deferred())` or somesuch. You shouldn't really be constructing `Deferred`s in threads, so something is broken here.